# Robocopy Windows Application C# Return Code 16

Tags: c#, windows, windows-server-2012, robocopy

I am using **robocopy command** using **windows app c#** move file from **one server** to **other server** have file size around **170 GB**. It was working fine earlier but it suddenly throw error with following exception detail:

“**Return Code: 16 (Robocopy did not copy any files. Check the command line parameters and verify that Robocopy has enough rights to write to the destination folder.)**“

Can anyone have any idea about this issue?

Comment: Did the destination server run out of space?

Comment: There is already 904 GB free space of drive.

Comment: What does the log say when you pass /LOG:file?

Comment: Return Code: 16  here is code description explained: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/deploymentguys/2008/06/16/robocopy-exit-codes/

Comment: Well, presuming the rights didn't actually change, the only thing I've seen that randomly causes a problem like that is anti-virus software. Is that a possibility? If not, you might want to CHKDSK the source and destination computers and even restart them to rule out a disk issue or OS state issue

Comment: lol :) it's working perfectly while running through command prompt. I think this issue can be around permissions or need to configure few more things through windows scheduler. moreover, it was running fine while I selected "Run this while user is logged on" after then changed to "Run this while user is logged on or not" I think from this change started the issue.

Comment: That is a critical piece of information. You should have an account you use for scheduled jobs that has the right permissions.

Comment: yes, it might be issue around permissions so planning with admin permissions or may be alternate to SQL Server Agent job scheduler with "SA" username.

Answer (score -1):

When I get this error, it is usualy because of an invalid parameter on the robocopy command line.
In this case, you can read in the robocopy log a line like:

- ERROR : invalid parameter **#n** : **value**

where **#n** is the position of the invalid parameter and **value** is the value of the invalid parameter.